# Apache redirect to index.php

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I've  got the below virtual host configuration on Centos 6.5 running apache 2.4.

```
<VirtualHost *:4323>
        ServerName www.first.com
        ServerAlias first.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/first.com
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php$1 [L,R=301]
        ErrorLog /var/www/first.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/first.com/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to `server_IP:4323` the default HTTP page comes up. How could I get the redirection to `index.php` working please?

The `httpd.conf` configuration is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvim27sazz9w00j/httpd.conf?dl=0)

The apache details below -

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar 22 2016 19:03:53
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf`, change*

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

To

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Or multiple :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<VirtualHost *:4323>
        ServerName www.first.com
        ServerAlias first.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/first.com
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php$1 [L,R=301]
        ErrorLog /var/www/first.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/first.com/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart apache.

Comment: Remove the `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteRule` directives. They are not required since you now have the `DirectoryIndex` set correctly (the `$1` is erroneous in the `RewriteRule` substitution).

Comment: Agree with "remove the RewriteEngine and RewriteRule directives", *unless* you had your site up with index.html for a while, and people might have set bookmarks to index.html.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` for it to load .php first but if it does not exist (like the site runs on .html), then it will serve the .html file.